# Smooth Jagged Lines into Curves

Tags: geometry, curves

If there are algorithms that approximates curves into jagged lines, is there any way to do it in reverse? Given a jagged lines, we have to smoothens the lines into forming curves?

My purpose is I want to smoothen the first image borders but not removing the curves. I want it to look naturally as the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since your question is quite vague there are many possible answers. You could for example do a least squares fit (linear regression, polynomial regression etc.) or use a kernel smoother.

Comment: @pg_star please see my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Given a smooth curve, take discrete points along it and join adjacent pairs by line segments.

Given such a sequence of connected line segments, find their intersection points and use a B spline fit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.